# How to take a screenshot of the console output in linux?

Tags: linux, console, screenshot

how can I make a screenshot of the linux console output?

For example I run the command `ls -l` and want to make a screenshot of the whole output.

Comment: Output redirection sounds like what you want.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of "screenshot" of what kind of console output?

I assume you meant to take a screengrab of the text consoles (the ones spawned by `getty`) rather than an emulated terminal, since the latter runs in a graphic environment where screen-grabbing would be mostly trivial.

If by screenshot you mean a text recording of some shell session, you can use the `script` program (see `man 1 script`).  The output (often containing control characters) can be then `cat`ted to the terminal for viewing.

If instead you mean an image file of the visible screen, you can try the various programs such as [`fbdump`](http://www.rcdrummond.net/fbdump/) or [`snapscreenshot`](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/source/snapscreenshot.html).  [Here](http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/how-to-make-screenshot-in-devtty-console-on-gnu-linux-taking-picture-jpeg-png-snapshot-of-text-console-in-systems-without-graphical-environment/) is an explanatory post about the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Ways

1. You can try the following commands:

   > gnome-screenshot 
   >   gnome-screenshot -w -B
2. You can simply redirect your output into a file, like so:

   > *linux command* > output.txt

Further references:  
 
 http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/screenshot-ubuntu/
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674327/redirect-all-output-to-file
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591374/command-output-redirect-to-file-and-terminal